# Using Java to send "Double Click" signal to MS Word

Tags: java, automation, ms-word

I am an automation programmer for a certain company and product.
I need to automate a few things with MS Word (on all versions, but I'll cross that bridge when I get there, if needed)
Most of the work is done, but I need to add a specific action to the automation: Double-Click a file in the word "Open File" window, to open it.

Until now, I used "Send Keys" to do that, sending the following key signals:

```
"^o";{TAB};{TAB};{TAB};{TAB};{TAB};{TAB};{TAB};{TAB};{TAB};{TAB};{TAB};test;{ENTER}
```

Which basically chose the file and opened it. That proved to be unsatisfactory as I specifically need to double click.

Is there a way I can accomplish doing so?

I program mainly in Java, but if you have a simple suggestion with another language, please go ahead.
It's enough just to double click the highlighted component, I could just use the above keys to get to the file, have it highlighted, and have it get the dbl.click signal.

NOTE:

> I could use Selenium or AutoIT but I was asked to not do that if
>   possible.

If anything is not clear enough, please do not hesitate to ask.

Oh yes, I forgot to mention something quite important - these automation tests work on a remote system, connected using Tomcat.

Update:

```
I put the idea on a back burner after wasting an entire day on this. I have found that     using JNA and User32 is fairly simple for mouse control, but I did not manage to     find the coordinates of the selection focus. 
If anyone has any idea, it is much appreciated!
```

Comment: Have you looked at the java.awt.Robot class?  It is intended for this type of activity.  A double click should simply be two mousePress/mouseRelease requests quickly.

Comment: Yes, I can see that working if I had the coordinates of the file icon. Is there a way to get the highlighted object's coordinates?
Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: @AdamCohen i guess there is no way to find those coordinates at least no straight forward way.